# How do I use a different highlighter in R Bookdown?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, bookdown

I am trying to change the syntax highlighting color scheme in my book when rendering to a GitBook-style webpage. The color schemes available in Pandoc aren't very informative for my code (HTML/CSS/JavaScript). I can modify the CSS directly to change the color scheme, but the underlying problem seems to be that the `highlighting-kate` library used isn't doesn't do very descriptive parsing of these languages to produce effective color schemes.

The compiled book looks like it contains a [highlight.js (HLJS)](https://highlightjs.org/) based [plugin for Gitbook](https://plugins.gitbook.com/plugin/highlight), but I can't figure out how to enable that so that I can drop in a hljs CSS file.

Is there anyway to utilize HLJS instead of Kate for code parsing? Or is there a good way to inject my own custom parsing into Pandoc's markdown rendering process?